# How to Communicate with a Chess engine in Python?

Tags: python, process, python-3.x, chess

On Windows 7 I can communicate with a chess engine via command line. Small example session with [Stockfish](http://www.stockfishchess.com/) on Win 7:

```
C:\run\Stockfish>stockfish-x64.exe
Stockfish 2.2.2 JA SSE42 by Tord Romstad, Marco Costalba and Joona Kiiski
quit

C:\run\Stockfish>
```

The first line was output by the engine and the 'quit' was what I typed to quit the engine (There are [other things I can do](http://wbec-ridderkerk.nl/html/UCIProtocol.html), but that's clear to me).

Now I want to communicate with that engine from python:

```
import subprocess
engine = subprocess.Popen(
    'stockfish-x64.exe',
    stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
)
for line in engine.stdout:
    print(line.strip())
engine.stdin.write('quit\n')
```

and I get

```
C:\run\Stockfish>communicate.py
b'Stockfish 2.2.2 JA SSE42 by Tord Romstad, Marco Costalba and Joona Kiiski'
```

But it doesn't quit the engine (no `C:\run\Stockfish>` prompt), it keeps waiting for input. I have to close the window by hand. It seems not to get my quit message (last line of the python script) written to stdin.

In other words, I can read from stdout but when I write to stdin nothing happens.

What am I doing wrong and how to do it right?

Comment: The `C:\run\Stockfish>` prompt is from your shell; why would you expect a subprocess to print it?

Comment: Do expect it to see that my python script is finished.

Comment: This was very helpful, thank you for sharing!

Comment: Code didn't work for me until I added an additional argument to `Popen`:    `..., bufsize=1, ...`

Comment: Thanks @DariusDuesentrieb, seems to have changed meanwhile. I added it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got a deadlock: the subprocess is waiting for input, while your program is waiting for it to output more lines in

```
for line in engine.stdout:
    print(line.strip())
```

This loop only stops when the subprocess closes its `stdout`.

Comment: Thanks, that was helpful. How to get all lines currently in stdout? Tried `engine.stdout.readlines()` and `engine.stdout.read()`

Comment: @Nils: both will try to read until the stream is exhausted, i.e. closed on the other end. Check the documentation for the program you are communicating with and try to comply with its output protocol; if it's designed to be communicated with, it should be documented how many lines it will send.

Answer (score 3):

You might want to use asyncio like python-chess does.
See

[engine.py](https://github.com/niklasf/python-chess/blob/master/chess/engine.py)

and the example from the [documentation](https://python-chess.readthedocs.io/en/latest/engine.html)

```
import asyncio
import chess
import chess.engine

    async def main():
        transport, engine = await chess.engine.popen_uci("/usr/bin/stockfish")

        board = chess.Board()
        while not board.is_game_over():
            result = await engine.play(board, chess.engine.Limit(time=0.1))
            board.push(result.move)

        await engine.quit()

    asyncio.set_event_loop_policy(chess.engine.EventLoopPolicy())
    asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: @Nils thx for the comment. You are kindly invited to discuss things at https://gitter.im/python-chess/community

Comment: Nice, looks like you found a solution. In case anyone else is considering python-chess, pondering and infinite/indefinite (stoppable) analysis are supported (https://python-chess.readthedocs.io/en/latest/engine.html#indefinite-or-infinite-analysis).

Comment: For example in these docs i can find a start() and a quit() function, but no stop() and no position() function.

Comment: @Nils Something like https://paste.debian.net/1127901/? Also available in the non-async API. Will expand the documentation if this helps. Using `readyok` to synchronize is totally fine.

Comment: Stackoverflow comments are probably not the right place for this. It looks like the exception is logged, not raised. Root cause is that the example quits while the second analysis is still ongoing. Will try to make the log less scary ... Btw. line numbers of the backtrace do not match the latest python-chess version.

Comment: Three years later. pythonchess still does not support the full UCI standard. All it provides is a bloated OOP API. Have fun reading the manual.

Comment: @Nils Lindemann - thank you for sharing your opinion on this. https://gitter.im/python-chess/community is IMHO a far better place for such discussions.

Answer (score 2):

I move my edit in the question into this answer.

Thanks to larsmans´ help, I solved it.

Example Python script:

```py
import subprocess, time

engine = subprocess.Popen(
    'stockfish14.exe',
    universal_newlines=True,
    stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
    bufsize=1,
)

def put(command):
    print('\nyou:\n\t'+command)
    engine.stdin.write(command+'\n')
    
def get():
    # using the 'isready' command (engine has to answer 'readyok')
    # to indicate current last line of stdout
    engine.stdin.write('isready\n')
    print('\nengine:')
    while True:
        text = engine.stdout.readline().strip()
        if text == 'readyok':
            break
        if text !='':
            print('\t'+text)

get()
put('uci')
get()
put('setoption name Hash value 128')
get()
put('ucinewgame')
get()
put('position startpos moves e2e4 e7e5 f2f4')
get()
put('go infinite')
time.sleep(3)
get()
put('stop')
get()
put('quit')
```

Output:

```
C:\run\chessengines\Stockfish>communicate.py

engine:
        Stockfish 14 by the Stockfish developers (see AUTHORS file)

you:
        uci

engine:
        id name Stockfish 14
        id author the Stockfish developers (see AUTHORS file)
        option name Debug Log File type string default
        option name Threads type spin default 1 min 1 max 512
        option name Hash type spin default 16 min 1 max 33554432
        option name Clear Hash type button
        option name Ponder type check default false
        option name MultiPV type spin default 1 min 1 max 500
        option name Skill Level type spin default 20 min 0 max 20
        option name Move Overhead type spin default 10 min 0 max 5000
        option name Slow Mover type spin default 100 min 10 max 1000
        option name nodestime type spin default 0 min 0 max 10000
        option name UCI_Chess960 type check default false
        option name UCI_AnalyseMode type check default false
        option name UCI_LimitStrength type check default false
        option name UCI_Elo type spin default 1350 min 1350 max 2850
        option name UCI_ShowWDL type check default false
        option name SyzygyPath type string default <empty>
        option name SyzygyProbeDepth type spin default 1 min 1 max 100
        option name Syzygy50MoveRule type check default true
        option name SyzygyProbeLimit type spin default 7 min 0 max 7
        option name Use NNUE type check default true
        option name EvalFile type string default nn-3475407dc199.nnue
        uciok

you:
        setoption name Hash value 128

engine:

you:
        ucinewgame

engine:

you:
        position startpos moves e2e4 e7e5 f2f4

engine:

you:
        go infinite

engine:
        info string NNUE evaluation using nn-3475407dc199.nnue enabled
        info depth 1 seldepth 1 multipv 1 score cp 90 nodes 33 nps 33000 tbhits 0 time 1 pv e5f4
        info depth 2 seldepth 2 multipv 1 score cp 336 nodes 72 nps 36000 tbhits 0 time 2 pv e5f4 a2a3 d8h4 e1e2
        info depth 3 seldepth 3 multipv 1 score cp 322 nodes 115 nps 57500 tbhits 0 time 2 pv e5f4 g2g3 f4g3
        info depth 4 seldepth 4 multipv 1 score cp 160 nodes 438 nps 219000 tbhits 0 time 2 pv e5f4 d2d3 d8h4 e1e2
        info depth 5 seldepth 5 multipv 1 score cp 38 nodes 1463 nps 365750 tbhits 0 time 4 pv e5f4 g1f3 g8f6 b1c3 d7d5
        info depth 6 seldepth 6 multipv 1 score cp 41 nodes 2424 nps 404000 tbhits 0 time 6 pv e5f4 g1f3 g8f6 b1c3 d7d5 e4d5 f6d5
        info depth 7 seldepth 7 multipv 1 score cp 41 nodes 3409 nps 426125 tbhits 0 time 8 pv e5f4 g1f3 g8f6 b1c3 d7d5 e4d5 f6d5
        info depth 8 seldepth 11 multipv 1 score cp 43 nodes 4937 nps 448818 tbhits 0 time 11 pv d7d5 g1f3 d5e4 f3e5 f7f6 b1c3 f6e5 d1h5 e8d7
        info depth 9 seldepth 11 multipv 1 score cp 4 nodes 14604 nps 486800 tbhits 0 time 30 pv d7d5 g1f3 e5f4 e4d5 g8f6 f1c4 f6d5 e1g1 d5b6
        info depth 10 seldepth 13 multipv 1 score cp 24 nodes 16663 nps 490088 tbhits 0 time 34 pv d7d5 g1f3 e5f4 e4d5 g8f6 f1c4 f6d5 e1g1
        info depth 11 seldepth 16 multipv 1 score cp 49 nodes 24347 nps 486940 tbhits 0 time 50 pv e5f4 f1c4 d7d5 e4d5 g8f6 b1c3 c7c6
        info depth 12 seldepth 19 multipv 1 score cp 46 nodes 58792 nps 477983 tbhits 0 time 123 pv e5f4 g1f3 g7g5 h2h3 d7d5 e4d5 d8d5 b1c3 d5e6 d1e2
        info depth 13 seldepth 19 multipv 1 score cp 45 nodes 88777 nps 482483 tbhits 0 time 184 pv e5f4 f1c4 d7d6 b1c3 d8h4 e1f1 c8e6 c3d5 h4d8 g1f3
        info depth 14 seldepth 17 multipv 1 score cp 50 nodes 120394 nps 483510 tbhits 0 time 249 pv e5f4 f1c4 d7d5 c4d5 d8h4 e1f1 b8c6 d2d4 g7g5 b1c3 f8g7 g1f3 h4h5
        info depth 15 seldepth 19 multipv 1 score cp 52 nodes 192828 nps 480867 tbhits 0 time 401 pv e5f4 f1c4 g8f6 b1c3 c7c6 d2d4 d7d5 e4d5 c6d5 d1e2 f8e7 c4b3 e8g8 c1f4 e7b4 g1f3
        info depth 16 seldepth 22 multipv 1 score cp 59 nodes 309617 nps 475602 tbhits 0 time 651 pv e5f4 f1c4 g8f6 b1c3 c7c6 d2d4 d7d5 e4d5 c6d5 c4b5 b8c6 c1f4 f8d6 f4d6 d8d6 d1e2 c8e6 b5c6
 b7c6 g1f3
        info depth 17 seldepth 26 multipv 1 score cp 34 nodes 955333 nps 476237 hashfull 65 tbhits 0 time 2006 pv e5f4 f1c4 b8c6 d2d4 d8h4 e1f1 d7d6 g1f3 c8g4 c4b5 h4h5 b1c3 e8c8 b5c6 b7c6 c
1f4 f7f5 d1d3 g8f6 d4d5 f5e4 d3a6 c8d7
        info depth 18 seldepth 28 multipv 1 score cp 44 nodes 1132938 nps 477227 hashfull 78 tbhits 0 time 2374 pv e5f4 f1c4 c7c6 d2d4 d7d5 e4d5 c6d5 c4b5 b8c6 c1f4 g8f6 b1c3 f8b4 g1f3 b4c3
b2c3 e8g8 e1g1 c8g4

you:
        stop

engine:

you:
        quit

C:\run\chessengines\stockfish>
```