# Communicating with console apps

Tags: go

I am a beginner. I have tried to communicate to a chess engine with go's `exec` package, but it requires me to close the stdin. What I wish to do is to establish a dialogue with the engine.

How do I do that with go?

This is the python implementation of the communication which is pretty much straight forward, can be found at [How to Communicate with a Chess engine in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12341882/how-to-communicate-with-a-chess-engine-in-python)

```
    import subprocess, time

    engine = subprocess.Popen(
    'stockfish-x64.exe',
    universal_newlines=True,
    stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
    )

    def put(command):
    print('\nyou:\n\t'+command)
    engine.stdin.write(command+'\n')

    def get():
    # using the 'isready' command (engine has to answer 'readyok')
    # to indicate current last line of stdout
    engine.stdin.write('isready\n')
    print('\nengine:')
    while True:
        text = engine.stdout.readline().strip()
        if text == 'readyok':
            break
        if text !='':
            print('\t'+text)

    get()
    put('uci')
    get()

put('setoption name Hash value 128')
get()
put('ucinewgame')
get()
put('position startpos moves e2e4 e7e5 f2f4')
get()
put('go infinite')
time.sleep(3)
get()
put('stop')
get()
put('quit')
```

For simplicity consider this in go:

```
package main

import ( 
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "os/exec"
)

func main() {
    cmd := exec.Command("stockfish")
    stdin, _ := cmd.StdinPipe()
    io.Copy(stdin, bytes.NewBufferString("isready\n"))
    var out bytes.Buffer
    cmd.Stdout = &out
    cmd.Run()
    fmt.Printf(out.String())
}
```

The program waits without printing anything. But when I close the stdin the program prints the result, but closing the stdin hinders communication between the engine and go program.

The solution:

```
package main

    import ( 
        "bytes"
        "fmt"
        "io"
        "os/exec"
        "time"
    )

    func main() {
        cmd := exec.Command("stockfish")
        stdin, _ := cmd.StdinPipe()
        io.Copy(stdin, bytes.NewBufferString("isready\n"))
        var out bytes.Buffer
        cmd.Stdout = &out
        cmd.Start()
        time.Sleep(1000 * time.Millisecond)
        fmt.Printf(out.String())
    }
```

Comment: Can you show us the code that does not work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should still be able to do this with `exec.Command` and then with the Cmd methods `cmd.StdinPipe()`, `cmd.StdoutPipe()`, and `cmd.Start()`

The example in the docs for exec.Cmd.StdoutPipe should be able to get you started: http://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/#Cmd.StdoutPipe

But in your case, you'd be doing reads and writes from the pipes in a loop. I'd imagine your architecture will look like this loop in a goroutine, passing commands to-and-fro the rest of your code via channels.

Comment: yes I will be able to invoke an external app using exec but it requires closing the stdin which blocks the communication.

Comment: Don't use `cmd.Run()`, use `cmd.Start()`. `Run` blocks and waits for the command to complete. `Start` lets you interact with the stdin/stdout while the program continues to run.