# Stockfish and Python

Tags: python, chess

I'm trying to write a script using python to feed chess positions into stockfish and get evaluations.

My question is based on this,
[How to Communicate with a Chess engine in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12341882/how-to-communicate-with-a-chess-engine-in-python)

The issue is with subprocess.pipe.

```
import subprocess, time
import os

os.chdir('C:\Users\Michael\Downloads\stockfish-6-win\stockfish-6-win\Windows'


engine = subprocess.Popen('stockfish', universal_newlines=True, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

def put(command):
    print('\nyou:\n\t'+command)
    engine.stdin.write(command+'\n')

def get():
    # using the 'isready' command (eng has to answer 'readyok')
    # to indicate current last line of stdout
    engine.stdin.write('isready\n')
    print('\nengine:')
    while True:
        text = engine.stdout.readline().strip()
        if text == 'readyok':
            break
        if text !='':
            print('\t'+text)

put('go depth 15') 
get()
put('eval')
get() 
put('position fen rnbqkbnr/pppppppp/8/8/8/8/PPPPPPPP/RNBQKBNR w KQkq - 0 1') 
get()
```

I'm getting an invalid syntax error on the comma after stdin=subprocess.PIPE

Any help fixing that or trying another method is appreciated.

Comment: This sounds weird to me. Maybe try deleting the space and rewriting it : it can be a thin space that is displayed as a space in fixed width fonts ; if you accidentally typed Alt+Space for example. (That assumes there is actually an error at the place python tells you ; I believe the missing parenthesis I hadn't seen before reloading the answers should start the syntax error at the `def` keyword)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a missing `)` in your third line:

`os.chdir('C:\Users\Michael\Downloads\stockfish-6-win\stockfish-6-win\Windows'`

should be `os.chdir('C:\Users\Michael\Downloads\stockfish-6-win\stockfish-6-win\Windows')`

Comment: Yeah, I was missing a parentheses.

Comment: No worries, happens to the best of us.

Answer (score 2):

The line

```
os.chdir('C:\Users\Michael\Downloads\stockfish-6-win\stockfish-6-win\Windows'
```

is missing a closing parenthesis. You probably wanted

```
stockfish_cmd = 'C:\\Users\\Michael\\Downloads\\stockfish-6-win\\stockfish-6-win\\Windows\\stockfish'
engine = subprocess.Popen(
    stockfish_cmd, universal_newlines=True,
    stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Note the doubling of backslashes as well, although I believe it just happens to be harmless in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I put a script for returning the Stockfish position evaluation on [github](https://gist.github.com/notbanker/3b87146ab0e2a4fd9740). Also a python wrapper [here](https://gist.github.com/notbanker/3af51fd2d11ddcad7f16).